# NSColor and its hue component

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscolor, hue

I don't quite understand why the hue component of NSColor behaves like it behaves. Here is something strange:

```
NSColor *c = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedHue:0.1 
                                  saturation:1.0 
                                  brightness:1.0 
                                       alpha:1.0]; 
CGFloat hue = 0.0; 
[c getHue:&hue saturation:NULL brightness:NULL alpha:NULL]; 
NSLog(@"hue = %f", hue);
```

If you run this code you see "hue = 0.1" being logged. But if you run the following code:

```
NSColor *c = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedHue:0.0 
                                  saturation:1.0 
                                  brightness:1.0 
                                       alpha:1.0]; 
CGFloat hue = 0.0; 
[c getHue:&hue saturation:NULL brightness:NULL alpha:NULL]; 
NSLog(@"hue = %f", hue);
```

You see "hue = 1.0" being logged. Is this a bug? I read a lot of documentation on Color Spaces and Colors in general and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In color theory, [hue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) is an [angular unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Units), usually expressed in [degrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28angle%29) [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) 360 (`0°` being the same as `360°`).

`NSColor` maps `0°` to the floating point value `0.0` and `360°` to `1.0`. Therefore, it's perfectly valid for `getHue` to return `1.0` instead of `0.0`, because both values represent the same hue.

Comment: I knew that hue is an angular unit - but it didn't occur to me that 360° is the same as 0° although it should be obvious. Thank you for pointing it out. :)